# Error while doing http request : undefined:1 <head><title>Document Moved</title></head>

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, node-modules

Getting error while doing http request in node. while i using code like following i get the error.

I tried like following code :

```
const http = require('http')

class postalData {

 async getPostData(pinCode){
  let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get('http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/' + pinCode,(res)=>{
      let data = '';

      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err.message);
    });  
  })
  const newLocal = await result
  return newLocal
 }
}

const getData = new postalData()
console.log('Post data : ', getData.getPostData(400705))
```

Getting error of below  doing http request in node. while i using code like following i get the error. like below:

```
undefined:1
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/rahul/indian-post/a.js:23:22)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

My Expected output :

```
{
   "Message":"Number of Post office(s) found: 1",
   "Status":"Success",
   "PostOffice":[
      {
         "Name":"Sanpada",
         "Description":"",
         "BranchType":"Sub Post Office",
         "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
         "Taluk":"NA",
         "Circle":"NA",
         "District":"Thane",
         "Division":"New Mumbai",
         "Region":"Mumbai",
         "State":"Maharashtra",
         "Country":"India"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a plain http call, but the server is responding with a `redirect` (Document Moved). node `http` will not follow the redirect, so it responds with the HTML for the redirection.

You can use [`request` package](https://github.com/request/request) in order to follow the redirection, or a simpler package like [`follow-redirects`](https://github.com/follow-redirects/follow-redirects). They provides a drop-in replacement for node `http` which follows redirects.

EDIT: If you don't want to use external libraries, just check response headers and statusCode like `request` do:

```js
if (response.statusCode >= 300 && response.statusCode < 400 && response.headers['location']) { /* retry the http request at the location */ }
```

Comment: i don't want to use external libraries like `request`

Answer (score 2):

The request `http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/400705` results in a `301 Moved Permanently` response with the the header `Location: http://www.postalpincode.in/api/pincode/400705` that tells you that the resource is available at `http://www.postalpincode.in/api/pincode/400705`.

If you open `http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/400705` in the browser it will automatically handle that `301` response and open that given location.

The `http` module of node does not do that, it gives you the actual response (which is the intended behavior of the `http` module)

If you want to use that module then you need to write you own logic to follow the redirect or use a library like `request` wich provides an option to follow these redirects.

You need to check the [`response.statusCode`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode) if it is `301` or `302`, if so you need to get the `Location` header using [`response.getHeader(name)`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_getheader_name), and re-issue the request, for the new response you would need to do the same in case another redirect happens there.

Comment: i don't want to use external libraries like `request`